# Why is only a quarter of the screen showing in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, display, screen

Only the top left quarter of my Ubuntu 22.04.1 desktop is showing on VirtualBox 6.1.30. I've installed Guest Additions CD. apt updated and restarted twice.

I've tried Xubuntu and Kubuntu 22.04 and they both work without any errors.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. After I disabled wayland everything works fine for me. To disable wayland see [How to share a screen in MS Teams or Zoom from Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405195/how-to-share-a-screen-in-ms-teams-or-zoom-from-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: Thanks. I don't know I didn't comment on this. To fix it, you need to choose log out. Although log out will fail the screen will then start working. You have to do this every time you log in.

Comment: You can disable wayland completely if you type `sudoedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`. And then uncomment the value `waylandEnabled=false` -- just remove the #. It described in the link. Reboot your system and then everything is fine.